# How can I adjust the space between vector elements using the print() function?

Tags: r, printing, paste

I wish to print the following text,

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

with the contents of the set {a,...,j} being an integer vector.

```
x = 1:10
print(c("x = {", x, "}"), quote=FALSE)
#[1] x = { 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    }
```

```
x = 1:10
noquote(paste(c("x = {",x,"}"),sep=","))
#[1] x = { 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    }
```

Both of these have the same output and the same two issues-- too many spaces and no commas between vector entries. I'm aware this is a very beginner question but any tips?

Answer (score 1):

`print` is not designed to paste element together, use `paste` instead:

```r
paste0("x = {", paste(x, collapse = ", "), "}")
#[1] "x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}"
```

A `tidyverse` alternative:

```r
library(stringr)
library(glue)
glue("x = {{{str_flatten_comma(x)}}}")
#[1] "x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}"
```